# Referring to another answer

Tags: discussion, answers

I recently found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750275/why-does-gaps-between-tiles-in-an-orthogonal-tilemap-cocos2d-game-appear-when-ru/28632627#28632627) in a first post review queue.  I wasn't sure how to review this answer, so I skipped it.  Basically, the answer referred to another answer (on the same question), and mentioned that some extra tweaking was needed for the solution to work for his personal system.

I was considering these actions:

- No Action/Minor formatting Edits.  This answer expands on the existing one by considering (possible) deficiencies.
- Comment to warn the new user.  This answer would be potentially better as a comment.  The answer did potentially provide a more-complete solution, but the user mentioned that this worked for *his system* with the specified setup.  That setup may or may not have been relevant to the OP's quesiton.

What would be the best actions(s) to take in this situation?  I just wasn't sure what to do with this "extension of an answer".  Is this appropriate as a new answer, or is more of a comment/edit?  Also does the extra "these were the extra fixes for my setup" change the quality of the answer?

Comment: The only thing I see wrong with that answer is that it doesn't link to the other answer it's extending, which can be a problem on questions with many answers.  What exactly do you think is wrong with this answer?

Comment: *"That setup may or may not have been relevant to the OP's quesiton"* it may be relevant to someone elses.

Comment: @KevinB ok so does that mean that this extension is perfectly valid answer (pending a few formatting edits).

Comment: I almost want to say it should have instead been a comment, but... It's far better formatted and easier to read as an answer than it ever would have been as a comment, i would leave it alone. (this coming from someone with little to no knowledge in the tech the question was asked)